# SQL server 2008 Task Scheduler will not create a file from the program

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008

I am running sql server 2008 and I have a .exe file on it that creates a .txt file which is saved in the same directory.  (so, before running just the .exe file exists, after running the .exe, the .exe file and a .txt file exist.) From there, the .exe file sends an email using that .txt file as an attachment.

Here is what works perfectly:  If I double click on the .exe file, the .txt file is created and the email is sent. or if a .txt file is already there, it is overwritten with a new one.  If I double click on the batch file which runs the .exe, it works too.

Here is what doesn't work:  If I try to start either the .exe or the .bat file in the Task Scheduler that is on the server, it will do something very peculiar:  The .txt file will not be overwritten or created.  If the .txt file doesn't exist, a new one isn't created and no email is sent.  If I put an old .txt file there, the email will get sent but with the old file (i.e. the file was not overwritten).  So, condensing it all down:  The task scheduler will not allow the .exe file to create the .txt file.  Just for fun, I modified the program (it was created with C++) so it only creates a .txt file with no email and it still won't create the .txt file.

Comment: Sounds like a security issue to me -- what credentials is the task running under?  Are you sure the process starts?

Comment: I'm not sure what creds would be for this.  First time using a server and time scheduler.

Comment: Here is the data from the event log:

User "OLYMPUS\"  updated Task Scheduler task "\PDAutomation"

Task Scheduler launched "{c6eb4bfb-a1c3-40a7-87c7-0973f8e41ab6}"  instance of task "\PDAutomation" due to a time trigger condition.

Task Scheduler started Task Engine "S-1-5-21-2114788981-1653766190-837300805-77880:OLYMPUS\:Password:"  process. Command="taskeng.exe" , ProcessID=2108, ThreadID=4116

Comment: Task Scheduler started Task Engine "S-1-5-21-2114788981-1653766190-837300805-77880:OLYMPUS\:Password:"  process.

Task Engine "S-1-5-21-2114788981-1653766190-837300805-77880:OLYMPUS\:Password:"  received a message from Task Scheduler service requesting to launch task "\PDAutomation" .

Comment: Task Scheduler started "{c6eb4bfb-a1c3-40a7-87c7-0973f8e41ab6}" instance of the "\PDAutomation" task for user "OLYMPUS\ ".
Task Scheduler launched action "C:\PDAutomation\run.bat" in instance "{c6eb4bfb-a1c3-40a7-87c7-0973f8e41ab6}" of task "\PDAutomation".
Task Scheduler launch task "\PDAutomation" , instance "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe"  with process ID 3156.

It is missing a task for Action completed and Task completed

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using code like:

```
if (!File.Exists("logfile.txt"))
{
     log = new StreamWriter("logfile.txt");
}
else
{
     log = File.AppendText("logfile.txt");
}
```

I find when running taskscheduler it is better to use the full path like this:

```
if (!File.Exists("c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Company\\Sales Report\\logfile.txt"))
{
       log = new StreamWriter("c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Company\\Sales Report\\logfile.txt");
}
else
{
       log = File.AppendText("c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Company\\Sales Report\\logfile.txt");
}
```

This also applies when reading a file.